# mysql avg on conditional

Tags: mysql, average

is it possible to get the average value for a column, as well as the average value for the same column with a conditional? or simply to combine these two queries into one.

```
SELECT AVG( field ) from table

SELECT AVG ( field ) from table where col = some_val
```

If there isn't a simple way to combine them using native mysql functions, would a stored function be able to handle it, or a user defined function?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Taking advantage of the fact that `null` values are not included in aggregate functions, we can use a `CASE` statement to control the average, as in the following:

```
select avg(amt) as average,
       avg(case when col=some_val then amt else null end) as conditionalAverage
  from myTable;
```

Sample Demo: http://sqlize.com/2IXwbWD2Eb

Answer (score 16):

There is another way, not using case when

```
select 
   avg(amt) as average, 
   avg(if(col=some_val,amt,null)) as conditionalAverage
 from myTable
```